# My mouse as stopped working - cursor does not respond at all but trackpad works (details inside)

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, mouse, input-device

I have a secondary computer that I use once a week or so. It runs Win7. Today I booted it up and found that my mouse was not responding at all. The cursor would just stay in the center of the screen. Neither clicking nor moving helped. I am trying to get it working again, but without luck. This is what I have found so far.

- I have tried two separate mice. Neither mouse worked.
- I have tried two separate USB ports. Neither port worked with the mouse, but both worked fine when a usb keyboard was attached
- When I used the mouse on a different machine, it worked just fine.
- When I used the built-in touchpad, that worked just fine.
- When I booted into Windows Safe mode, the mouse still did not work.
- When I booted this same machine into Ubuntu, the mouse worked perfectly.
- I have tried "rolling back" the mouse driver. That did not work.
- Upgrading the driver back to current did not work either.
- I have tried toggling Legacy USB Mode in the BIOS. No luck there.
- The mice are nothing fancy. No special drivers are required. They just use the standard windows provided driver.

It is rare that I ever install something new on this machine. It is set up with a few things I need, and there is little need to change it. I cannot remember the last time I actually installed something new. I usually use it for browsing the web or playing Starcraft. Occasionally some Adobe Illustrator.

The only new thing I have started doing new lately is using the windows "Remote Assistance" feature to control this computer from another computer. Even then, when I was using that, nothing seemed to be the problem.

Does anyone know what I might look into to get this working properly again?

Thanks.